# Meaning of "passeggiata di salute"

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence in a [Quora answer](https://it.quora.com/Cosa-manca-alla-saga-di-Star-Wars-per-essere-ancora-migliore):

> Dopo la grandissima, prima trilogia, le hanno provate tutte per rinverdire i fasti di Star Wars. La prosopopea familiare portata all'esasperazione con colpi di scena a ripetizione su parentele che al confronto Beautiful è una passeggiata di salute (e L'Ascesa di Skywalker è l'apice).

What does "passeggiata di salute" mean here? "health walk" does not make sense in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Passeggiata di salute* would indeed literally mean a walk, seen as something that is good for one's health; however, it is more often used to mean something leisurely, unproblematic. A bit like “easy-peasy”, perhaps.

So, in this context, the writer mentions a soap opera like *The Bold and the Beautiful* (*Beautiful* in Italian), renowned for its frequent and often far-fetched dramatic turns of events, to say – quite hyperbolically – that, compared to the last *Star Wars* films, that soap opera was straightforward and and not at all reliant on sensational revelations.

<sup>All in all, I wouldn't take that Quora answer as a model of Italian style. It itself relies quite a bit on hyperbole and not-exceedingly-well-mastered rhetorical devices: *rinverdire i fasti*, *prosopopea familiare*...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A similar idiom in English is "a walk in the park".